# React: Not able to catch current event value for inputbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I have been working on a customized input box in react. Subsequently, I am not able to access the current events value. Below is the code snippet:

Parent Component:------------------------------------------------------------------

```
<Input
          value={this.state.value ? this.state.value : ''}
          onChange={this.onInputChange}
          onBlur={this.onBlur}
          onFocus={this.onFocus}
        />

    onInputChange = (e) => {
        this.setState(
          {
            value: e.target.value
          }
        );
      };
```

---

Child Component:------------------------------------------------------------------

```
<input
      value={this.state.value}
      onChange={this.onChange}
    />

     onChange = () => {
        if (this.state.value.length === 0) { // Not able to access actual value, getting previous state's 
         value and subsequently the length is 1, when there is no value present in the input box.
          console.log('onchangeeeeeeeeeeee', this.state.value); 
        }
    }
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using synthetic event. you might have to check the wiring of react events.

Comment: Hello, can you please go into more detail about what a synthetic event is and maybe give an example?

Comment: Hello, In the code snippet given in the question, the parent component event (onInputChange function) which is browsers native event.  And if you would see in the child component , if we try to pass an event to onChange Function, it would be synthetic event. SyntheticEvent is kind of a wrapper around the browser’s native event.